# Is it mandatory to upgrade to latest fb sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook

For the new apps to be uploaded on appstore, is it mandatory to upgrade to latest fb sdk? Will old sdk result in any kind of rejection? I am aware that few of graph api support has been stopped to directly post on friends wall. But we are using the dialogs only. Can anyone provide a link confirming whether upgrade to latest sdk is mandatory or not?

Comment: I don't think apple will reject it, but some things might stop working.

Comment: @jcesar Ok thanks for the reply.I found few apis related to direct posting on friends wall has been stopped functioning in Graph api. But, I was unable to find if its compulsory for new apps to update to new fb sdk or not.

Comment: I don't know which version I integrated in one of my apps, but it's from november, and facebook posting is still working. I updated that app 2 weeks ago and was approved by apple.